# Can HAProxy load a userlist from a file?

Tags: haproxy, http-basic-authentication

I can't seem to see anything in the documentation, but this seems like an obvious feature. I want to supply a file containing a list of users for Basic Authentication. I don't want to edit the HAProxy config file every time a new user is added.

The [documentation](http://www.haproxy.org/download/1.6/doc/configuration.txt) only gives examples of users specified directly in the file. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2):

You can use a `-f` option multiple times when running haproxy.
See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25775682/can-i-split-a-large-haproxy-config-file-into-multiple-smaller-files

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are right. There is no such feature in haproxy according to its documentation.

You need to modify your config file each time you want to add a new user, but this should not be bad as far as it is sufficient to do graceful reload.

Comment: Thanks, I thought so. My user list is automatically updated, and I do not want to automatically update my haproxy file, or reload the config. Looks like I'll have to use nginx.